# Android Spinner onItemSelected not triggered

Tags: android, methods, listener, spinner, adapter

Good day.

I tried choosing the items from my Spinner dropdown list. But when I clicked on the dropdown list items the dropdown list des not closes.

I started debugging and realize that when I click on the dropdown list item the method onItemSelected is not triggered. However, when the dropdown list was first initialized the method is triggered.

Is there any way to trigger the onItemSelected when the Spinner dropdown list item is clicked?

Below is my code for the Spinner Activity and my Cursor Adaptor class.

```
public class ActivitySearch extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  {
private EditText mSearchTextInput;
private TextInputLayout mSearchTextTextInputLayout;
private AppCompatSpinner mMySpinner;
private AppCompatButton mSearchButton;
private String mModName;
private SearchTextWithSpinnerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_text_with);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mSearchTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTextInput);
    mSearchTextTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchTextTextInputLayout);
    mMySpinner= (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mMySpinner);
    mSearchButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int defaultModName;
    if(extras != null) {
        mSearchTextInput.setText(extras.getString(ARG_SEARCH_KEYWORD, ""));
        mModName = extras.getString(ARG_MOD_NAME, "");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_invalid_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //Set adapter for spinner list
    mAdapter = new SearchTextWithSpinnerAdapter(this, null, -1, new SearchTextWithSpinnerAdapter.ListViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSpinnerItemClicked(String count) {

            mMySpinner.performClick();

            int defaultModName;

.........................

            mMySpinner.setSelection(defaultModName);

            if (mMySpinner!= null) {
                try {
                    Method method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(mMySpinner);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mMySpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    mMySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    mMySpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mMySpinner.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    });

    mMySpinner.setSelection(defaultModName);
    mMySpinner.setSelected(true);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mMySpinner.setSelection(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { }...

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // data is not available anymore, delete reference
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

This is my CursorAdapter:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ListViewListener mCallback;

public interface ListViewListener {
    void onSpinnerItemClicked(String count);
}

private static class ViewHolder  {
    LinearLayout myRow;
    ImageView profileImage;
    TextView NameText;
    TextView DescText;
}

public SpinnerAdapter (Activity activity, Cursor data, int flags, ListViewListener listener) {
    super(activity, data, flags);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mCallback = listener;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view_activity_search_text_with, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.Row = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myRow);
    viewHolder.profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    viewHolder.NameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    viewHolder.DescText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DescText);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    viewHolder.Row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onSpinnerItemClicked(xxx);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably because the `onTouch` listener is being called. Why not put that code in the `onItemSelected()`?

Comment: I tried removing this line of code:

'mMySpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mMySpinner.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    });'


But it still can detect the onItemSelected method,

Comment: @codeMagic The 'mMySpinner.setOnTouchListener' method.

Comment: *"But it still can detect the onItemSelected method"* ***can*** or ***can't***?

Comment: @codeMagi  Sorry for the inconvenience caused. It's can't. The onItemSelected method still can't be triggered.

Comment: Do you have any other listeners set on it that I missed? How do you know it's not being called? Did you set a breakpoint or log statement in there?